# Splitting a string to remove surrounding < and > characters

Tags: perl, split

I have a string like this `<name>`, I want to chop off the `<>` and take out only  `name` and put it into a variable.

How to do it using perl "split" function?

Comment: as you've specified the language as `perl`, I've added it as a tag on your question. It's generally a good idea to put the language as a tag as it'll help people who're "language x" experts find your question and help you answer it =)

Comment: you can use Regex also as : <([^>]+), it will give you name only.

Comment: Why do you want to use split? Don't you just want to accomplish the task in the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex and matching in list context:

```
my $s = "<name>";
my ($name) = $s =~ /<(.*)>/;
```

Comment: This method is very useful it works perfectly...
Thanks buddy ..i used " /<(\S*)>/ " ...

Comment: You probably want the non-greedy quantifier on that *, just in case.

Comment: Or use `/<([^>]*)>/` to make it explicit (both to `perl` and to future readers of your code) that you're looking for *non-'>'* characters rather than *any character at all* (which is what `.` means in a regex).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). That's like using the wrong end of a screwdriver to hammer in nails. I'd do it in some step with a match where you capture the part that you want in list context:

```
 my( $var ) = $input =~ /<(.*?)>/;
```

Alternatively, you could just remove the brackets with one of these:

```
 $input =~ tr/<>//;
 $input =~ s/[<>]//g;
```

Answer (score -1):

In answer to you question about how to do it using split then you can do this:

```
$input ="<string>";
print split(/[<>]/,$input);
```

[Click for live example](http://codepad.org/8wkXYoyP)

A better method however would be

```
$input = "<string>";
print $input =~ /<(.*)>/;
```

[Click for live example](http://codepad.org/3K1vDEX9)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not too sure why you'd want to use split for that... but here it goes:

```
> perl -le'$str="<string>";print split("<",(split(">",$str))[0]);'
string
```

Comment: Why not `split( /[<>]/, $str )`?